# Cannot change modem config Thomson TG789vn

Tags: port-forwarding, modem

I have a Thomson TG789vn modem and a Archer c5 router. Now, I want to set my modem to bridge mode, so I watched a tutorial for that exact modem and it says I should click 'Setup my Thomson Router', but that button simply isn't there. What should I do? contact my ISP?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but have you tried to RTFM on how to do it manually (without easy wizards)?

Comment: no, I've read some more info and it turns out that my ISP doesn't allow me to switch it into bridge mode...

Comment: Well then you can call their helpdesk and complain while knowing this ain't helping. Or you could ditch ISP provided routers and ask if they could just give you a modem and pick your own router (i have this and it is way better than ISP router).